# Pandas: How can I check if a pandas dataframe contains a specific value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Specifically, I want to see if my pandas dataframe contains a False.

It's an nxn dataframe, where the indices are labels.

So if all values were `True` except for even one cell, then I would want to return False.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is a bit confusing, but assuming that you want to know whether there is at least one False in your dataframe, you could simply use

```
mask = df.mycol == False
mask.value_counts()
mask.sum()
mask.sum() > 0
```

All will tell you the truth

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to scan your **whole dataframe** looking for a value, check `df.values`. It returns an array of all the rows in the dataframe.

```py
value = False  # This is the value you're searching
df_contains_value = any([value in row for row in df.values])
```